# Show X axis ticks and labels in scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I was building a scatterplot to correlate the abundance of certain organisms with Temperature. While building the graph I realized that the x axis values do not appear.

This is an example of how my dataset looks like:

```
> dput(head(abundance))
structure(list(OGA_ID = c(20L, 22L, 66L, 75L, 91L), sample_ID = structure(c(5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("TARA_N010000218", "TARA_N010000238", 
"TARA_N010000911", "TARA_N010000955", "TARA_N010000980"), class = "factor"), 
    vlookup = c(2.6820250147109e-06, 4.2504952889635e-07, 3.098736273373e-07, 
    4.7282955865616e-07, 6.4437058525603e-07), relative.abundance = c(2.6820250147109e-06, 
    4.2504952889635e-07, 3.098736273373e-07, 4.7282955865616e-07, 
    6.4437058525603e-07), log = c(-5.57153717588776, -6.37156046083652, 
    -6.50881538403584, -6.32529538161919, -6.19086429282228), 
    station = structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("TARA_188", 
    "TARA_205", "TARA_210"), class = "factor"), depth = structure(c(2L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("DCM", "MES", "SRF"), class = "factor"), 
    size.fraction = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("[>0.8µm]", 
    "[0.8-20µm]"), class = "factor"), temperature = c(61.5754, 
    72.4693, 72.4456, 78.3555, 61.5754)), row.names = c(NA, 5L
), class = "data.frame")
```

This is my code:

```
{r, fig.width=10, fig.height=5}
library(ggplot2)

abundance_environment <- read.table('/home/agalvez/data/environmental_data/vanellid/environmental_parameters.csv', sep="\t", header=TRUE)

lineplot <- ggplot(abundance_environment, aes( x = abundance_environment$temperature...C., y = abundance_environment$log, group = abundance_environment$Depth_Nominal , colour = abundance_environment$Depth_Nominal)) +
  geom_point( size =2, shape =16) + 
  xlab("Temperature(ºC)") + ylab("Relative abundance") + ggtitle("Abundance-Temperature") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(colour = "Depth") 

  
lineplot
```

I do not see why the axis are hidden. Could someone help me with that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example by either sharing a snippet of data in a copy-pastable format or using a built-in dataset?

Comment: To make it easy for others to copy your data, please use `dput(head(abundance_environment))`. What you have now is hard to copy-paste.

Comment: I am sorry! Is this format easier to copy?

Comment: Yes - this is better. But the variable names in your data don't match the `ggplot()` call. Can you show an example of what your plot looks like, because I am getting a normal plot with x axis labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with my code was that I was specifying the dimensions of the plot and this was hiding the x-axis.

So I solved it by changing `{r, fig.width=10, fig.height=5}` by simply `{r}`.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few issues here.

1. When you call your variables to map them in `ggplot(aes())`, you should use just the unquoted variable name (e.g. `ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp))` rather than `ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mtcars$disp))`
2. The variable names in the data you shared don't match what's in your ggplot call. E.g. you are calling `x = abundance_environment$temperature...C.` but the variable in the data you shared is called `temperature`. This lead me to wonder if you're accidentally plotting another version of the data that's in your environment. Perhaps just try clearing your environment and re-loading the data and plot.
3. When I plot your data snippet after fixing the above issues, the plot looks as I would expect with `x` axis values. If you are also getting this result, please clarify what you want it to look like.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- structure(list(temperature = c(61.5754, 72.4693, 72.4456, 78.3555, 61.5754), log = c(-5.57153717588776, -6.37156046083652, -6.50881538403584, -6.32529538161919, -6.19086429282228), depth = structure(c(2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("DCM", "MES", "SRF"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

d %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = temperature, y = log, colour = depth)) +
  geom_point(size =2, shape =16) + 
  xlab("Temperature(ºC)") + 
  ylab("Relative abundance") + 
  ggtitle("Abundance-Temperature") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(colour = "Depth")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>